# SharePointGroupID for PeoplePicker

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker, external-users, person-or-group

I added my PeoplePicker like this:

```
initializePeoplePicker: function(peoplePickerElementId) {
    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SharePointGroupID'] = 5;
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '100%';

    SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
},
```

But in this case the discover will give all the users even the external users, I tried  :

```
schema['SharePointGroupID'] = 'Everyone except external users';
```

but it doesn't work, and the discover doesn't work.

Any idea to grant restriction for discovering external users in  PeoplePicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to retrict the person or group field to select the users from only single group and not any external users than that group(correct me if I am wrong).

So, In such cases you need to use `SharePointGroupID` property of client site people picker schema.

**SharePointGroupID**: It allow to get users from specified group only.

**References**:

1. [How to use Client Side People Picker In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/client-side-people-picker-in-sharepoint-2013) : This demonstrates how to use `SharePointGroupID` property of schema.
2. [Use the client-side People Picker control in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in).
3. [ClientPeoplePicker properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj175898(v=office.15)).

**Note** : If you are already using `SharePointGroupID` and passing the ID of SharePoint Group then please check that you are passing the correct group ID.

**How to check the Group ID**:

1. **From UI** :
   Go to site settings --> Site Permissions --> Select the required group --> see for `MembershipGroupId` query string parameter in URL of page.
2. **Using REST**:

   `<Sitename>/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Group Name')?$select=id`

Comment: hi , Ganesh , as you can note i already used the schema['SharePointGroupID'] = 5; the 5 is the ID of the group : _layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=5 , but still dosent exlude external users

Comment: Strange.....Are you sure that 5 is the correct ID of the group(Try to find the ID using methods given in my answer) and the external users(users you are seeing while testing this people picker) are not added to the group?

Comment: yes, the users are not added to any group !! strange , and the title of spgroup is: "Everyone except external users"

Comment: just for note, my external users are added directly to the group 'members'  !!!

Comment: ok , the solution for me now, is to create a new group to fill it the external users , and then , it works , thank you Ganseh

Comment: welcome @ImenTurki

Answer (score 0):

The `ClientPeoplePicker` class does not have a property to exclude external users from resolution.

As `@Ganesh Sanp` mentioned, the `ClientPeoplePicker.SharePointGroupID` property is used to limit resolution to members of a SharePoint Group. The property value type is `Int32`. You need to put the ID of a SharePoint Group.

More information about [ClientPeoplePicker properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj175898(v%3Doffice.15)).

Currently, we cannot achieve that. 
Here is a UserVoice "[Hide external users from people picker](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/32240545-hide-external-users-from-people-picker)", you can vote it up.

As a **workaround** to exclude external users from resolution of a people picker, you can add all users except external users to a SharePoint group, then you can configure people picker to restrict user selection to a certain group.

Comment: actualy there already a group for "exclude external user" and am based on that , here is :t/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=5, schema['SharePointGroupID'] = 5;

Comment: Check the group settings of this group, see if Everyone can view the membership of the group.

Comment: And ensure the client-side people picker control is used in the site where the group exists.

Comment: just for note, my external users are added directly to the group 'members' !!!

Comment: You are using the "SharePointGroupID" to limit resolution a certain group "exclude external user". Add users to another group would not cause that. Please check  the group settings of this group, see if Everyone can view the membership of the group. And ensure the client-side people picker control is used in the site where the group exists.

Comment: So, I found out that the "exclude external user" , it an account : Account c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/fdb7fb83-fcc9-4284-955d-a4895d4d5658
Title Everyone except external users